# How can I use custom javascript in Spring Roo generated pages?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, dojo, spring-roo

I have been working on a spring roo project and I've hit a wall in terms of being able to customize the web page.

The main thing I want to do is be able to dynamically hide certain fields as the client is filling out the web form. I have a drop down list driven by enumerations that has 4 options and a fifth "other" option. If the user selects "other" I want a text box to appear so the user can fill out their own selection.

I was talking to someone and they said "This really depends on the UI you choose. In case of MVC scaffolding you can use javascript to drive these relationships". I am indeed using MVC scaffolding so I guess I have to use javascript. I don't really know that much javascript but the problem lies in that I don't even know where the javascript code would go in term of my project files. And then the second problem of course is how to use javascript to hide the fields dynamically in Spring.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring MVC scaffolding uses dojo by default as its javascript framework.

You are able to use standard dojo functions when you attach events to DOM elements. You can simply use the `<script/>` tag to contain your own custom javascript methods within a generated `.jspx` page.

Additionally, you can integrate another existing javascript framework such as jQuery. At the moment you can include jQuery manually, but it can possibly be expected in a future Spring Roo version.

You can play safe with dojo for now.